# is there online citrix testing available?

Tags: terminal-services, citrix

Is there any way to access CITRIX remotely for doing some simple QE testing, our customer has a compatibility issue with our product and we dont have CITRIX in house

PS: Also VMWARE image would be an option

Comment: Similar to my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030145/acquiring-accessing-citrix-environment-for-qa-purposes -- an answer to one may answer the other as well.

Answer (score 0):

A VMware appliance from Citrix would be a great idea. Also, they used to have a developer version but appreciate it's not trivial to set-up.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the Citrix Ready virtual lab and test kit available from http://community.citrix.com/citrixready

Citrix owns the Xen hypervisor that powers its XenServer product.  Any virtual appliances that Citrix provides will be for the Xen hypervisor, and not VMware's.